# Increase command timeout in EF6

Tags: entity-framework-6

How can I increase CommandTimeout in Entity Framework 6.

I can increase in

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
     public partial class ModelContainer : DbContext
        {
           public ModelContainer() : base("name=ModelContainer")
           {
               ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = 600;    
           }
        }
```

But it get lost every time I update model. 
Is there any work-around for this?

Comment: could you find any solution ?#

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is the auto-generated code gets overwritten every time you refresh your Model. There are two ways to accomplish this:

1) The slightly complicated way: Created an inherited class for your Model, and set the CommandTimeout in the inherited class. In your code, use the inherited class instead of the ModelContainer class.

2) The easier way: create an overloaded constructor for your Model in a seperate .cs file so it doesn't get overwritten. Basically, you could create an additional file called something like ModelProperties.cs. In that file, put:

```
public partial class ModelContainer
{
    public ModelContainer(int timeout) : base()
    {
        ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CommandTimeout = timeout;
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you create a new ModelContainer in your code, you can pass the desired timeout into the constructer: var myModelContainer = new ModelContainer(600);